# configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables in mac os terminal

Tags: c, macos, compiler-construction, terminal, ios-4.2

i'm trying to Building libCURL in iOS 4.2, i do some steps in the terminal.
The steps are :

1. `cd curl-7.21.2`
2. `export CC=/Developer\ 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.0.1`
3. `export CFLAGS="-isysroot /Developer\ 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk"`
4. `export LDFLAGS="-isysroot /Developer\ 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk -Wl,-syslibroot /Developer\ 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk"`
5. `export CPP=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/cpp`
6. `./configure --disable-shared --without-ssl --without-libssh2 --without-ca-bundle --without-ldap --disable-ldap --host=arm-apple-darwin10`

but after tap enter the terminal show me these warnings and errors :

```
configure: WARNING: if you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.
    If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking whether to enable debug build options... no
checking whether to enable compiler optimizer... (assumed) yes
checking whether to enable strict compiler warnings... no
checking whether to enable compiler warnings as errors... no
checking whether to enable curl debug memory tracking... no
checking whether to enable c-ares for DNS lookups... no
checking for sed... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for arm-apple-darwin10-ar... no
checking for ar... /usr/bin/ar
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin10-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking curl version... 7.21.6
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin10.6.0
checking host system type... arm-apple-darwin10
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for arm-apple-darwin10-gcc... /Developer 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.0.1
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/sikmac2/desktop/curl-7.21.6':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

this is the config.log :

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by curl configure -, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.68.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --disable-shared --without-ssl --without-libssh2 --without-ca-bundle --without-ldap --disable-ldap --host=arm-apple-darwin10

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = sikmac2s-MacBook.local
uname -m = i386
uname -r = 10.6.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 10.6.0: Wed Nov 10 18:13:17 PST 2010; root:xnu-1504.9.26~3/RELEASE_I386

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 10.6.0: Wed Nov 10 18:13:17 PST 2010; root:xnu-1504.9.26~3/RELEASE_I386
Kernel configured for up to 2 processors.
2 processors are physically available.
2 processors are logically available.
Processor type: i486 (Intel 80486)
Processors active: 0 1
Primary memory available: 2.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 84 tasks, 416 threads, 2 processors
Load average: 0.49, Mach factor: 1.65
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/X11/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2693: checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles
configure:2702: result: no
configure:2719: checking whether to enable debug build options
configure:2738: result: no
configure:2742: checking whether to enable compiler optimizer
configure:2763: result: (assumed) yes
configure:2775: checking whether to enable strict compiler warnings
configure:2794: result: no
configure:2798: checking whether to enable compiler warnings as errors
configure:2817: result: no
configure:2821: checking whether to enable curl debug memory tracking
configure:2840: result: no
configure:2854: checking whether to enable c-ares for DNS lookups
configure:2876: result: no
configure:2898: checking for sed
configure:2917: found /usr/bin/sed
configure:2930: result: /usr/bin/sed
configure:2947: checking for grep
configure:2966: found /usr/bin/grep
configure:2979: result: /usr/bin/grep
configure:2995: checking for egrep
configure:2998: result: /usr/bin/grep -E
configure:3054: checking for arm-apple-darwin10-ar
configure:3088: result: no
configure:3098: checking for ar
configure:3117: found /usr/bin/ar
configure:3129: result: /usr/bin/ar
configure:3208: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:3276: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:3287: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:3324: result: yes
configure:3386: checking for gawk
configure:3416: result: no
configure:3386: checking for mawk
configure:3416: result: no
configure:3386: checking for nawk
configure:3416: result: no
configure:3386: checking for awk
configure:3402: found /usr/bin/awk
configure:3413: result: awk
configure:3424: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:3446: result: yes
configure:3520: checking for arm-apple-darwin10-strip
configure:3550: result: no
configure:3560: checking for strip
configure:3576: found /usr/bin/strip
configure:3587: result: strip
configure:3624: checking curl version
configure:3626: result: 7.21.6
configure:3667: checking build system type
configure:3681: result: i386-apple-darwin10.6.0
configure:3701: checking host system type
configure:3714: result: arm-apple-darwin10
configure:3752: checking for style of include used by make
configure:3780: result: GNU
configure:3816: checking for arm-apple-darwin10-gcc
configure:3843: result: /Developer 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.0.1
configure:4112: checking for C compiler version
configure:4121: /Developer 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.0.1 --version >&5
./configure: line 4123: /Developer: is a directory
configure:4132: $? = 126
configure:4121: /Developer 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.0.1 -v >&5
./configure: line 4123: /Developer: is a directory
configure:4132: $? = 126
configure:4121: /Developer 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.0.1 -V >&5
./configure: line 4123: /Developer: is a directory
configure:4132: $? = 126
configure:4121: /Developer 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.0.1 -qversion >&5
./configure: line 4123: /Developer: is a directory
configure:4132: $? = 126
configure:4151: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:4173: /Developer 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.0.1 -isysroot /Developer\ 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk  -isysroot /Developer\ 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk -Wl,-syslibroot /Developer\ 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk conftest.c  >&5
./configure: line 4175: /Developer: is a directory
configure:4177: $? = 126
configure:4215: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "curl"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "curl"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "-"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "curl -"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "a suitable curl mailing list: http://curl.haxx.se/mail/"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "curl"
| #define VERSION "-"
| #define OS "arm-apple-darwin10"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int main (void)
| {
| 
|  ;
|  return 0;
| }
configure:4220: error: in `/Users/sikmac2/desktop/curl-7.21.6':
configure:4222: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=i386-apple-darwin10.6.0
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value='/Developer 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.0.1'
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value='-isysroot /Developer\ 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk'
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPP_value='/Developer 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/cpp'
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value='-isysroot /Developer\ 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk -Wl,-syslibroot /Developer\ 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk'
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=arm-apple-darwin10
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=arm-apple-darwin10
ac_cv_path_GREP=/usr/bin/grep
ac_cv_path_SED=/usr/bin/sed
ac_cv_path_ac_pt_AR=/usr/bin/ar
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_prog_AWK=awk
ac_cv_prog_CC='/Developer 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.0.1'
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_STRIP=strip
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
curl_cv_PATH_SEPARATOR=:

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} "/Users/sikmac2/desktop/curl-7.21.6/missing" --run aclocal-1.9'
AMDEPBACKSLASH='\'
AMDEP_FALSE='#'
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='${SHELL} "/Users/sikmac2/desktop/curl-7.21.6/missing" --run tar'
AR='/usr/bin/ar'
AS=''
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} "/Users/sikmac2/desktop/curl-7.21.6/missing" --run autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} "/Users/sikmac2/desktop/curl-7.21.6/missing" --run autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} "/Users/sikmac2/desktop/curl-7.21.6/missing" --run automake-1.9'
AWK='awk'
BUILD_LIBHOSTNAME_FALSE=''
BUILD_LIBHOSTNAME_TRUE=''
CC='/Developer 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.0.1'
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS='-isysroot /Developer\ 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk'
CONFIGURE_OPTIONS='" '\''--disable-shared'\'' '\''--without-ssl'\'' '\''--without-libssh2'\'' '\''--without-ca-bundle'\'' '\''--without-ldap'\'' '\''--disable-ldap'\'' '\''--host=arm-apple-darwin10'\'' '\''host_alias=arm-apple-darwin10'\'' '\''CC=/Developer 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.0.1'\'' '\''CFLAGS=-isysroot /Developer\ 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk'\'' '\''LDFLAGS=-isysroot /Developer\ 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk -Wl,-syslibroot /Developer\ 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk'\'' '\''CPP=/Developer 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/cpp'\''"'
CPP='/Developer 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/cpp'
CPPFLAGS=''
CROSSCOMPILING_FALSE=''
CROSSCOMPILING_TRUE=''
CURLDEBUG_FALSE=''
CURLDEBUG_TRUE=''
CURLVERSION='7.21.6'
CURL_CA_BUNDLE=''
CURL_CFLAG_EXTRAS=''
CURL_DISABLE_DICT=''
CURL_DISABLE_FILE=''
CURL_DISABLE_FTP=''
CURL_DISABLE_GOPHER=''
CURL_DISABLE_HTTP=''
CURL_DISABLE_IMAP=''
CURL_DISABLE_LDAP=''
CURL_DISABLE_LDAPS=''
CURL_DISABLE_POP3=''
CURL_DISABLE_PROXY=''
CURL_DISABLE_RTSP=''
CURL_DISABLE_SMTP=''
CURL_DISABLE_TELNET=''
CURL_DISABLE_TFTP=''
CURL_LIBS=''
CURL_NETWORK_LIBS=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR='.deps'
DLLTOOL=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C='\c'
ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP='/usr/bin/grep -E'
ENABLE_SHARED=''
EXEEXT=''
FGREP=''
GREP='/usr/bin/grep'
HAVE_GNUTLS_SRP=''
HAVE_LDAP_SSL=''
HAVE_LIBZ=''
HAVE_LIBZ_FALSE=''
HAVE_LIBZ_TRUE=''
HAVE_PK11_CREATEGENERICOBJECT=''
HAVE_SSLEAY_SRP=''
IDN_ENABLED=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='${SHELL} $(install_sh) -c -s'
IPV6_ENABLED=''
KRB4_ENABLED=''
LD=''
LDFLAGS='-isysroot /Developer\ 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk -Wl,-syslibroot /Developer\ 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk'
LIBCURL_LIBS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINT='#'
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE='#'
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} "/Users/sikmac2/desktop/curl-7.21.6/missing" --run makeinfo'
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
MANOPT=''
MIMPURE_FALSE=''
MIMPURE_TRUE=''
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
NO_UNDEFINED_FALSE=''
NO_UNDEFINED_TRUE=''
NROFF=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE='curl'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='a suitable curl mailing list: http://curl.haxx.se/mail/'
PACKAGE_NAME='curl'
PACKAGE_STRING='curl -'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='curl'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='-'
PATH='/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PERL=''
PKGADD_NAME='cURL - a client that groks URLs'
PKGADD_PKG='HAXXcurl'
PKGADD_VENDOR='curl.haxx.se'
PKGCONFIG=''
RANDOM_FILE=''
RANLIB=''
REQUIRE_LIB_DEPS=''
SED='/usr/bin/sed'
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SONAME_BUMP_FALSE=''
SONAME_BUMP_TRUE=''
SSL_ENABLED=''
STATICLIB_FALSE=''
STATICLIB_TRUE=''
STRIP='strip'
SUPPORT_FEATURES=''
SUPPORT_PROTOCOLS=''
TEST_SERVER_LIBS=''
USE_ARES=''
USE_AXTLS=''
USE_CYASSL=''
USE_EMBEDDED_ARES_FALSE=''
USE_EMBEDDED_ARES_TRUE=''
USE_GNUTLS=''
USE_LIBRTMP=''
USE_LIBSSH2=''
USE_MANUAL_FALSE=''
USE_MANUAL_TRUE=''
USE_NSS=''
USE_OPENLDAP=''
USE_POLARSSL=''
USE_SSLEAY=''
USE_WINDOWS_SSPI=''
VERSION='-'
VERSIONNUM='071506'
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__include='include'
am__leading_dot='.'
am__quote=''
am__tar='${AMTAR} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='${AMTAR} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='i386-apple-darwin10.6.0'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='i386'
build_os='darwin10.6.0'
build_vendor='apple'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='arm-apple-darwin10'
host_alias='arm-apple-darwin10'
host_cpu='arm'
host_os='darwin10'
host_vendor='apple'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='/Users/sikmac2/desktop/curl-7.21.6/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
libext=''
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(mkinstalldirs)'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
subdirs=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "curl"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "curl"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "-"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "curl -"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "a suitable curl mailing list: http://curl.haxx.se/mail/"
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define PACKAGE "curl"
#define VERSION "-"
#define OS "arm-apple-darwin10"

configure: exit 77
```

base on Bavarious comments, i've change all the command in every step, these are the update :

1. `export CC='\"/Developer 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.0.1\">`
2. `export CFLAGS="-isysroot \"/Developer 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk\""`
3. `export LDFLAGS="-isysroot \"/Developer 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk -Wl,-syslibroot \"/Developer 4.2/Platforms/icleaPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk"""`
4. `export CPP='\"/Developer 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/cpp">`
5. `./configure --disable-shared --without-ssl --without-libssh2 --without-ca-bundle --without-ldap --disable-ldap --host=arm-apple-darwin10`

but it make the terminal did not execute the command.

i dont understand what it is, can somebody tell me?

Thank you

Comment: It’ll help if you edit your question and paste the last few lines of config.log.

Comment: i have update my question, please see it

Comment: It looks like `configure` is not quoting the path to the compiler, which must be quoted because it contains spaces: `/Developer 4.2/`. Try exporting `CC` as `\"/Developer  4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.0.1\"

Comment: You might have to do that in all variables that reference `/Developer 4.2/`.

Comment: @Bavarious can you give me another clue about step 3, i'm doubt about the double quotes

Comment: Try `export CFLAGS="-isysroot \"/Developer  4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk\""`

Comment: @Bavarious i try all of your answer, but it make the terminal can not execute the command, it always give me '>' when i press enter, if i try /Developer 4.2/ it give me log that that command is wrong

Comment: I haven’t used autotools in a while so I’m not sure how to solve this. One possibility is to create a symbolic link without any spaces in its name and point it to `/Developer 4.2`. For instance, `sudo ln -s /Developer\ 4.2 /Developer4.2`, and then replace that in all your variables.

Comment: Why are you using the iPhone compiler?

Answer (score 8):

If you are on Lion try installing with the tag: `--with-gcc=clang`

Running `rvm requirements` explains this in more detail:

```
Xcode 4.2:
 * is only supported by ruby 1.9.3+ using command line flag: --with-gcc=clang
 * it breaks gems with native extensions, especially DB drivers.

Xcode 4.2 users - please be warned - 
in case of any compilation issues 
 * downgrade to Xcode 4.1
 * or install osx-gcc-installer
and reinstall your rubies.
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, since I didn't want Xcode installed. I used the `osx-gcc-installer` and `CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.9.3 --with-shared` on Lion to get ruby.

Comment: I was facing the same problem and after installing XCode Command Line Utilities everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the spaces in the pathnames.  What's more, there isn't an easy fix until you remove them.

The trouble is in the log file - it just appears near the middle of it...

```
configure:4112: checking for C compiler version
configure:4121: /Developer 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.0.1 --version >&5
./configure: line 4123: /Developer: is a directory
configure:4132: $? = 126
configure:4121: /Developer 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.0.1 -v >&5
./configure: line 4123: /Developer: is a directory
configure:4132: $? = 126
configure:4121: /Developer 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.0.1 -V >&5
./configure: line 4123: /Developer: is a directory
configure:4132: $? = 126
configure:4121: /Developer 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.0.1 -qversion >&5
./configure: line 4123: /Developer: is a directory
configure:4132: $? = 126
configure:4151: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:4173: /Developer 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.0.1 -isysroot /Developer\ 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk  -isysroot /Developer\ 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk -Wl,-syslibroot /Developer\ 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk conftest.c  >&5
./configure: line 4175: /Developer: is a directory
configure:4177: $? = 126
configure:4215: result: no
```

To get the paths with the spaces to work, you'd have to be able to ensure that whenever `CC` is used, the path is enclosed in double quotes.  You'd also have to fettle your `CFLAGS` value so that the path is not split but the `-isysroot` is separate from the path leading to `-isysroot`.

If you want to get adventurous, you can try using:

```
export CC="\"/Developer 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.0.1\""
export CFLAGS="-isysroot \"/Developer 4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk\""
```

There's an outside chance it will work, but I'd not want to rely on it.  Basically, it adds double quotes at judiciously selected points in the values of the environment variables, in the hope that the shell will manage to keep them in the right places.  I don't think it will work, but it might be worth a try.

I recommend renaming the path where you have the software installed without the space, maybe as:

```
/Developer-4.2/Platforms/...
```

(I had a directory `$HOME/External Source Repositories` briefly, with areas for `git` and `svn` and `hg` (Mercurial) copies of external source repositories, including the VCS's mentioned.  The VCS were OK with the spaces in the names, but the build processes for the downloaded repositories (including the VCS own build systems)  were not (`git` included, IIRC).  The directory is now called `$HOME/External-Source-Repositories` instead.)