# Why do I get a configure error when installing Ruby 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby

Anyone have an idea as to what this error means? I'm attempting to install Ruby 1.9.3

```
Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/Users/coreycallahan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml --with-opt-dir=/Users/coreycallahan/.rvm/usr ', please read /Users/coreycallahan/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.

$ cat /Users/coreycallahan/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/configure.log

[2012-04-10 11:10:33]  ./configure --prefix=/Users/coreycallahan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml --with-opt-dir=/Users/coreycallahan/.rvm/usr 
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-libyaml
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/coreycallahan/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3 (11D50d)

Comment: you should probably do `cat /Users/coreycallahan/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/configure.log` and print that output into the question as well. Or, `cat /Users/coreycallahan/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/configure.log|pbcopy` and it will save you having to copy it.

Comment: Try looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032824/cant-install-ruby-under-lion-with-rvm-gcc-issues)

Comment: Try to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134745/configure-error-c-compiler-cannot-create-executables-in-mac-os-terminal

Answer (score 0):

```
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

Do you have permission to write in the directory where you're compiling?

Comment: Try copying the files to a directory where you know you have permission to write.