# Homebrew - `brew install freetds` leads to: "configure error: C compiler cannot create executables"

Tags: xcode, gcc, homebrew

I'm using Xcode version 4.6.2.  I am trying to `brew install freetds`, but I'm running into some trouble.

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134745/configure-error-c-compiler-cannot-create-executables-in-mac-os-terminal), but still couldn't fix my error.

First, here's the error:

```
$ brew install freetds
==> Downloading http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/freetds/stable/freetds-0.91.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/freetds-0.91.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/freetds/0.91 --with-openssl=/usr/bin --with-tdsver=7.1 --mandir=/usr/local/Cellar/freetds/0.91/share/man
checking for gcc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/tmp/freetds-prGt/freetds-0.91':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

I'll walk through some of my system information.

```
$ brew update
Already up-to-date.

$ brew doctor
Your system is ready to brew.

$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc

$ which cc
/usr/bin/cc

$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ cc --version
cc (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0

$ xcrun clang --version
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
Thread model: posix

ls -la /usr/bin | grep .*gcc.*
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel           32 Jun 10 11:57 cc -> i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel           32 Jun 10 11:58 gcc -> i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel           32 Jun 10 11:57 gcc-4.0 -> i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel           32 Jun 10 11:58 gcc-4.2 -> i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel           28 May 26 16:10 gcov-4.2 -> ../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/gcov-4.2
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel           52 May 26 16:10 i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 -> ../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel           52 May 26 16:10 i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 -> ../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2
-rwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel       369408 Sep 23  2007 i686-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel           32 May 26 16:10 llvm-cpp-4.2 -> ../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-cpp-4.2
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel           32 May 26 16:10 llvm-g++ -> ../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-g++-4.2
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel           32 May 26 16:10 llvm-g++-4.2 -> ../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-g++-4.2
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel           32 May 26 16:10 llvm-gcc -> ../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel           32 May 26 16:10 llvm-gcc-4.2 -> ../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
-rwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel       369408 Sep 23  2007 powerpc-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1

$ ls /usr/bin | grep gcc
gcc
gcc-4.0
gcc-4.2
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2
i686-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1
llvm-gcc
llvm-gcc-4.2
powerpc-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1
```

I'm not terribly familiar with system issues like this.  Where is the config.log file (I know that's important for debugging this error)?  Does anyone see where my problem might be based on the information I provided?

Comment: Try brew with --debug and drop into shell when the error occurs (option 5). You'll then be in the directory that contains config.log.

Comment: Works in Xcode 5.0.1 -- can you try upgrading?